# ¿Cómo puedo enviar los datos de un JSON usando una api en c#?

Tags: c#, json, api

Hola necesito crear un formulario en C# que me guarde los datos en un JSON y éstos datos sean enviados a un servidor externo, ya tengo el token para hacer la conexión, pero no se cómo hacerlo, estoy usando Visual Studio 2019, el tipo de proyecto debe ser Aplicación Web ASP.NET(.NET FRAMEWORK) c#.

[image: Aquí tengo el formulario con los datos]

Al momento de dar clic en el botón de enviar debo recibir los datos del formulario y enviarlos al servidor externo.
[image: instrucciones para recibir los datos y enviarlos]

Encontré como realizar lo que quiero pero con Python y lo necesito con c#, les muestro el código de python que encontre:

```
import json
import requests
from bottle import route, template, run, static_file, request, response
@route('/create_ticket', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_form():
 if 'verified_email' in request.cookies:
    ask_email = False
else:
    ask_email = True
status = ''
if request.POST:
    # Get the form data
    #email = request.forms.get('email')
    if 'verified_email' in request.cookies:
        email = request.get_cookie('verified_email')
    else:
        email = request.forms.get('email')
    name  = request.forms.get('name')
    classification  = request.forms.get('classification')
    subject = request.forms.get('subject')
    description = request.forms.get('description')

    # Package the data for the API
    data = {'request': {
                        'email': email,
                        'custom_fields': [{'id': 360032359112, 'value': name},{ 'id': 369832402952, 'value': classification }],
                        'subject': subject,
                        'comment': {'body': description}                        
                        }
            }
                     
    ticket = json.dumps(data)

    # Make the API request
    user = email + '/token'
    api_token = 'yourtoken'
    url = 'https://www.urlprueba.com'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        data=ticket,
        auth=(user, api_token),
        headers=headers
    )
    if r.status_code != 201:
        if r.status_code == 401 or 422:
            status = 'No se pudo autenticar. Verifique su dirección de correo electrónico o regístrese.'
            ask_email = True
        else:
            status = 'Problema con la solicitud. Estado ' + str(r.status_code)
        #return status
    else:
        status = 'El ticket fue creado. Busque una notificación en su correo electrónico.'
        if 'verified_email' not in request.cookies:
            response.set_cookie('verified_email', email, max_age=364*24*3600)
            ask_email = False


return template('ticket_form', feedback=status, no_email=ask_email)

@route('/css/<filename>')
def send_css(filename):
  return static_file(filename, root='static/css')

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Espero su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Ana, coloca algo de código que hayas realizado aunque sea el nombre el método que enviaría la info, la clase con la que construirías el json, etc. Sino hay que darte un link para que leas documentación de como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone ya agregué un poco de código, espero puedan ayudarme, soy nueva en esto y agradecería mucho su apoyo, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la libreria `Newtonsoft`, te dejo el paso a paso de como serializar, deserializar un objeto de ejemplo que te hice, y una forma de conexion muy facil. Como no se a que token te referis ni que servicio, deberas adaptar la idea que te paso a tu necesidad, usando la libreria `HttpClient` para la conexion u otra similar. Veras que como pasas nada de informacion ni siquiera tu clase es complicado darte un ejemplo mas proximo a tu realidad.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    protected void Buttton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicioWeb(new Persona { Documento = 1234, Nombre = "MiNombre", Apellido = "MiApellido" });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async void ServicioWeb(Persona persona)
    {
        //Serializas tu objeto persona con la libreria Newtonsoft y la clase static JsonConvert, y el metodo Serialize lo hace automaticamente pasandole por parametro tu objeto Persona
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona);
        
        //Asi quedaria serializado tu objeto
        //{"Documento":1234,"Nombre":"MiNombre","Apellido":"MiApellido"}

        //Esta clase te permite hacer una conexion.
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //Creas el contenido que enviaras a traves de esa clase, le pasas tu json, le das un formato y por ultimo decis que sera del tipo json
        var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        //Usas el metodo post para enviar el contenido que creaste y le pasas la url del servicio al que queres comunicarte y le pasas
        //el resultado a la variable response para saber si el resultado fue ok o no.
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("UrlServicioWeb", content);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //tu servicio respondio bien y puedes hacer alguna accion si necesitas saber la respuesta
        }

        //Para desearlizar algun json, lo mas facil siempre es contar con el modelo del objeto como la clase persona
        //Le indicas el tipo de objeto al que tiene que deserializar y le pasas el json por parametro y en la variable j vas
        // a tener el resultado de tu objeto creado.
        var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(json);
    }
}
public class Persona
{
    public int Documento { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el código de python hace muchas cosas (es muy difícil de refactorizar si no se conocen las referencias web).

1. Si conoces lo que es un JSON sáltate esta parte un JSON es
   *JavaScript Object Notation* que se traduce a groso modo en un objeto separado por "{}" y ","  puesto en un string ejemplo

   ```
   {"departamento":8,"nombredepto":"Ventas","director": "juan rodriguez","empleados":[{"nombre":"Pedro","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"nombre":"Jacinto","apellido":"Benavente"}
   ```

   ]}

   Para realizarlo en c# necesitas estas librerías (o similares)

   ```
   using System.Text.Json;
   using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
   ```

   se realiza de esta forma  de forma sincrona

   ```
   var jsonObjeto= JsonSerializer.Serialize(tuObjeto); //el objeto retornante es un string
   ```

   de forma asincrona

   ```
   using (FileStream fs = File.Create(nombreDocumento))
   {
       await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, tuObjeto);
   }
   ```

   pero para convertir a json necesitas un objeto da igual si es
   anónimo `object[] values = { 123, "foo" };` [link objeto anonimo](https://sodocumentation.net/es/csharp/topic/765/tipos-anonimos)
   o si lo haces por una clase [link clases](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1)

Tras conocer esto pasamos a como comunicarnos a servicios externos.
Las formas mas sencillas son webreferences y WebRequest

2. Las webReferences son servicios que determinadas se cuelgan "online"
   como por ejemplo este [link](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx) esto te permite conocer que métodos
   tienen disponibles y la clase de parámetros que esperan y que te van
   a retornar [te dejo un vídeo sencillo de un ejemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKwyhUruFc8)
3. La otra forma es utilizando WebRequest la cual te dejo la
   documentación oficial de como realizarlo [doc Oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)

---

***Si tienes cualquier duda pregunta***